# Get MAC Address via powershell

Tags: powershell, get

I have a large number of devices (servers and workstations) that I need to gather network adapter MAC's and the associated IP's for.  I have a working script but for some reason, it does not return the MAC in the results.  Am I doing something wrong or am I not using the correct verbiage?

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -ComputerName ComputerName -Detailed | select ComputerName,macaddressipv4address
```

When I run the Get-NetIPConfiguration without the pipe, it does return a MAC address value.  But when I add in the select pipe, it only returns the computer name and IP address.  The MAC column is blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MacAddress` is a nested property in the `NetAdapter` property, you can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) to get it:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration -ComputerName ComputerName -Detailed |
    Select-Object ComputerName, @{ N='MacAddress'; E={ $_.NetAdapter.MacAddress }}, @{ N='IPv4Address'; E={ $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress }} |
    Export-Csv path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Another question you might be able to assist with.  I would like to export everything to a csv file.  Based on the current script, would I just need to pipe the select-object to the export-csv or would I need to do something a little different?

Comment: @MjrPayne yup that's all you need to do, pipe to export csv

Comment: I was typing out what I had and then noticed you edited the comment.  That is exactly what I have as well so Im glad Im on the same page!

Comment: So I set up the script like so:

```
$servers = Get-Content "path"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
Get-NetIPConfiguration -ComputerName ComputerName -Detailed |
    Select-Object ComputerName, @{ N='MacAddress'; E={ $_.NetAdapter.MacAddress }}, @{ N='IPv4Address'; E={ $_.IPv4Address.IPAddress }}
}
export-csv -path "path" -notypeinformation
```
It will still populate results in the IDE screen but the csv is empty.  Ideas?

Comment: Figured it out.  Had to move the closing bracket to after the -notypeinformation to include the export-csv.  Working perfectly now.